# Virt-Manager loses connection sometimes

Tags: 12.04, kvm-virtualization

I've been having an odd issue with virt-manager on 12.04. Generally speaking it works flawlessly, however sometimes it appears to lose connection. I've noticed that this will only occur if I 'reopen' it after closing it in the same session.

IE: Use it for a few hours, then close it out.
A few hours later I open it up again and I'm missing a connection to QEMU entirely.

Pictures are here:
Working:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUZoz.jpg

Not Working:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCDSX.jpg

I've seen a few bug reports around that say this type of behaviour was fixed in 9.1, which I'm currently on.

Is anyone else seeing this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That major version isn't specific enough, all of our updates are reflected in the suffix, if that fix is really installed it's 0.9.1-1ubuntu5. In any event, if you somehow found an escape for this fix, it's a bug, and doesn't belong here, it belongs in launchpad. Thanks.

https://launchpad.net/virt-manager

Thanks.

Comment: it's very possible that I have, however I haven't been able to reproduce it consistently at all. I'm trying to gauge if it's something *I'm* doing versus a code issue

Comment: I should also note that the bug reports that I was seeing for this were for Fedora, so it may not have made it into the ubuntu-specific release

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're doing anything out of the ordinary here, run the next invocation with strace to catch it in the act and continue with filling a proper bug report.